# Unable to Parse URL

Tags: java, android, url

I am trying to recover the url that contains the access_token and my refresh_token but I am unable to do so. The log output does not contain the url as shown below.

```
Uri result = getIntent().getData();
Log.d("url", result.toString());
```

Code used is as follows.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String AUTHORIZATION_URL = "https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/authorize";
    private static final String CLIENT_ID = "788....";

    private LinearLayout rootView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        rootView = new LinearLayout(this);
        rootView.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams llp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        tv.setLayoutParams(llp);
        rootView.addView(tv);
        setContentView(rootView);

        String action = getIntent().getAction();

        if (action == null || !action.equals(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)) { // We need access token to use Imgur's api

            tv.setText("Start OAuth Authorization");

            Uri uri = Uri.parse(AUTHORIZATION_URL).buildUpon()
                    .appendQueryParameter("client_id", CLIENT_ID)
                    .appendQueryParameter("response_type", "token")
                    .appendQueryParameter("state", "init")
                    .build();

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setData(uri);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);

            Uri result = getIntent().getData();
            Log.d("url", result.toString());

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to make an HTTP request?

Comment: with what I tried I get on the login page, I log in
 well, then a new page will appear with just the url. It is displayed in
the browser but I can not get it back: /